# How to add More angular directive's as a dependency to New custom Directive ?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to add more than one dependency directives to 'require' parameter
like

```
 directive("customDirective", function (scope,ele,attr) {
    return {
              require : ["directive1","directive2","directive3"],
              scope : {},
              link : function () {
                      // some stuff goes here
                     }
           };
 });
```

Is that `require` property correct..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it in array syntax.

```
require: ['^parentDirectiveName', '?optionalDirectiveName', '?^optionalParent']
```